# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10. How to prevent this?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the second-highest number from the list which takes in user input but I keep getting this-
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
I tried a sample case where n = 5 and I entered the list as [2,3,6,6,5] and I'm getting the same error

How do I go about it, the code is given below:

```
list1 = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(0,n+1):
    ele = int(input()) //error coming in this line
    list1.append(ele)

new_list = set(list1)
new_list.remove(max(new_list))
print(max(new_list))
```

this is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/submission/20220221/18/09/hackerrank-1dcd86ec44b50895801520a4a2d0e542/code/Solution.py", line 4, in <module>
    ele = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'
```

Comment: You can't literally enter the string `[2,3,6,6,5]`.  The way the code is written, you first enter the number of elements, and then enter each element one at a time.  (This is what happens when you get someone else to write your code for you but they don't document it!)

Comment: sure, I'll add the traceback as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ValueError%3A+invalid+literal+for+int%28%29+with+base+10, it would help you if you first extracted a [mcve] and then searched for similar problems.

Comment: @Jeffy Same problem; the code is written to accept each number as an individual piece of input, but you're trying to enter them all at once.  The problem isn't the code, it's that you aren't entering the data it expects.  Again, this would not be a problem if you'd read over and understood the code that you copied, or had the author explain it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly, you might want to *always* make a list, so you could do something like

- get the value
- remove the braces
- make a list of the entries by dividing them up by their commas (conveniently makes a list of length 1 if no comma is present!)
- convert them to integers

You can actually do this all at once with a List Comprehension wrapping the cleanup

```py
[int(x) for x in input().strip("[]").split(",")]
```

```
>>> [int(x) for x in input().strip("[]").split(",")]
1
[1]
>>> [int(x) for x in input().strip("[]").split(",")]
[1,2,3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

The rest follows from your work to make a `set` to remove duplicates, find the max, etc.

---

You could alternatively use `eval()` to convert strings into Python objects, but this is *highly dangerous* if you accept inputs from an unknown source (in the worst case, a totally unknown one such as an web client) as it directly exposes all the functionality and privilege of the process to the caller

Comment: ... or use `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: that's fair and should be safe! .. but also less instructive and flexible

Comment: is  .strip[] used to remove the braces?

Comment: yes, it'll remove all the given characters from the head and tail of the string! (it doesn't mind if they exist, but also won't check if they're balanced)